# Connecting to SOCKS5 Proxy via VBscript

Tags: vbscript, socks

I have tried and failed to connect to an URL through a SOCKS5 proxy using the VBscript below.

I get the `Parameter is Incorrect` error on the `xmlhttp.setProxyCredentials username, password` line, although the credentials are correct (checked 5x).

```
Function GetResult(url As String) As String
    Dim xmlhttp
    Dim ret As String
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    xmlhttp.setProxy 2, proxy
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", url, False
    xmlhttp.setProxyCredentials username, password
    xmlhttp.send
    ret = xmlhttp.responseText
    GetResult = ret
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

[ServerXMLHTTP uses WinHTTP on the backend](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/290761/frequently-asked-questions-about-serverxmlhttp). So, you are limited to the proxies that are [supported by WinHTTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winhttp/proxycfg-exe--a-proxy-configuration-tool), which only includes HTTP and HTTPS proxies, not SOCKS5.

> You can specify proxies in a space-delimited string. The proxy listings can contain the port number that is used to access the proxy. To list a proxy for a specific protocol, the string must follow the format, protocol=http://proxy_name. The valid protocols are HTTP and HTTPS. For example, to list an HTTP proxy, a valid string is http=http://http_proxy_name:80, where http_proxy_name is the name of the proxy server and 80 is the port number that you must use to access the proxy. If the proxy uses the default port number for that protocol, then you can omit the port number. If a proxy name is listed by itself, you can use it as the default proxy for any protocols that do not have a specified proxy. For example, http=http://http_proxy other_proxy uses http_proxy for any HTTP operations, while the HTTPS protocol uses the proxy named other_proxy.
>
> You can list locally known host names or IP addresses in the proxy bypass list. This list can contain wildcards, such as "*", that cause the application to bypass the proxy server for addresses that fit the specified pattern, for example, "*.microsoft.com" or "*.org". Wildcard characters must be the left-most characters in the list. For example, "aaa.*" is not supported. To list multiple addresses and host names, separate them with blank spaces or semicolons in the proxy bypass string. If you specify the macro, the function bypasses any host name that does not contain a period.

Digging a little further, [InternetExplorer/WinINet supports SOCKS4, but not SOCKS4a nor SOCKS5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2010/10/08/socks-proxies-in-internet-explorer/). That blog post also mentions that SOCKS isn't something Microsoft hears about from customers.

> To date, we've heard very little feedback about the limited support for SOCKS in IE. Most users are satisfied with the existing CERN-proxy support for HTTP/HTTPS/FTP traffic, and for cases where full socket proxying is required, VPN or RAS software is used instead. Note that it's also possible to use a proxy like Fiddler as a gateway/bridge to an upstream SOCKSv4a server. See this [StackOverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375234/enable-socks-4a-5-in-internet-explorer/18384592#18384592) for details.

The term [`CERN-proxy`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CERN_httpd) is just a HTTP proxy and is discussed more in "[How To FTP with CERN-Based Proxy Using WinInet API](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/166961)"